# When push my app to heroku, have error. -- "NameError: uninitialized constant Bookbank" in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It work in my local database

////////////////////////////////////////////////

Cmd window

```
      rake aborted!
      NameError: uninitialized constant Bookbank
      /tmp/build_66337ebf-8431-4ffb-9df9-a6a4b2783ab6/config/routes.rb:54:in `block
     in <top (required)>'
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

route

```
require 'grape'
Mytwitter::Application.routes.draw do


 ........

  mount Bookbank::API => "/api" #line 54
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but heroku doesn't understand module name  when precompile assets.

Change

from

```
  mount Bookbank::API => "/api"
```

to

```
  mount API => "/api"
```

and also you need to change app/api/bookbank/api.rb

from

```
module Bookbank
  class API
  ........
  end
end
```

to

```
class API
........
end
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I was having the same issue, but it was because I named my app namespace "App". I guess that confused the name resolution.